# How to locate a Darktable image on the filesystem?

Tags: darktable

Darktable does not have an "open in finder" or "open in explorer" option.

If I'm viewing an image and I want to locate the file in a file viewer, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The full path to the image should be shown in the "image information" tab on the left

Comment: That's not nearly as convenient because 1) it is ellipsized, so it cannot be copied, 2) must be typed out in full from the tooltip, 3) you have to manually open a file explorer and navigate there manually. Wow. But thanks, sounds like this is the only way.

Comment: You can always ask the DarkTable authors on the [mailing list](https://www.darktable.org/contact/#how-to-get-in-contact) or [the forum](https://discuss.pixls.us/c/software/darktable).

Comment: @Ana Yes, it is ellipsized, but, at least on my Linux version, when I copy and paste it, it still produces the full path. Perhaps that's different on non-Linux versions, but I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the full path is copied on Windows as well. Right-click, Select All, Ctrl+C to copy. If you extend the left panel sufficiently it's shown in full.